# Embed server side code in style property (.Net)

Tags: .net, styles, server-side

I would like to embed server side code in a style property of a .net control (on a web form in a web application):

```
<input runat="server" type="submit" 
 style='background-image:url(<%= Page.ResolveUrl("~/Images/search.gif") %>)' />
```

I want to reference an image with the root directory of the application. Unfortunately, it does not work.

Answer (score 1):

Your approach is right, however quotes are creating problem for parser. Try

```
Public imgPath As String = System.Web.VirtualPathUtility.ToAbsolute("~/Images/CommonBG.jpg")
```

in code and

```
<input runat="server" type="submit" 
 style="background-image:url('<%= imgPath %>')" />
```

Ensure you are not hosting in virtual directory or imgPath is accessible from browser.

Comment: Thanks for the help, but it doesn´t work yet. I tried using a public string member in code behind but the image is still not shown

Comment: View Source of the page output in browser, copy the url in background and open in browser to check if path is correct.